# Livewire 404 error when refreshing component with parameter

Tags: laravel-livewire

When i try to refresh (from his child) a component directly displayed by a route like this :

```
Route::get('/facility/{idinstall}', Facility::class)->where(['idinstall' => '[0-9.]+' ]);
```

Or when i try to upload file like in the documentation i got a 404 error message like this :

```
/livewire/message/stock.facility 404 (Not Found)
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Try `php artisan optimize:clear`?

Comment: I tried and same result, its an installation problem because it works on a fresh install of laravel,  but i discovered today its just on the first id with the url /facility/1, everything is ok when i use /2 /3 ...

Comment: It will throw a 404 if you have model-route-binding, and that the ID 1 does not return data.

Comment: Thats my problem, i got data in the 1 id, and its the only one doesnt work.

Comment: Sounds like more of an implementation issue than anything. Do you have any global scopes, how do you find the resource in the component?